# GIMP: how to create new file when executing gimp from CLI?

Tags: command-line, gimp, flag

(Sorry if this is too easy question, I'm just starting to use `gimp`).

I'm looking for following behavior in `gimp`. When executing `gimp a.png` from shell:

1. if `a.png` file exists, `gimp` opens `a.png` (Of course this works)
2. if it doesn't exist, create new blank image (named `a.png`) and then open that image in gimp. (I can't find this).

I'm just trying to reduce procedure of creating new file with `Ctrl-n` and so-on, so-on ..., if I know the new file-name and I'm already at that directory in terminal.

---

Things that I've tried:

- `gimp --as-new a.png`, still gets error stating file doesn't exits & I have to use `ctrl-n` and so-on.
- `convert -size 480x320 xc:white /tmp/new.jpg;  gimp /tmp/new.jpg`. This creating blank image with `imagemagick` first & then opening with `gimp`. This is the behavior I'm looking for. But this felt bit too hacky.

---

Questions:

1. Is there such thing (e.g. execution flag) for `gimp`?
2. Also what does `--as-new` flag do?, (I thought this was thing I was looking for)
3. Is `convert -size 480x320 xc:white /tmp/new.jpg;  gimp /tmp/new.jpg` the only way?